# Mongodb using Docker - using port 27016

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, port

My goal is to run a mongodb server using a docker container (on an EC2 instance) using port `27016`.
Then I want to read/write from/on this mongodb server from a second EC2 instance - using a jupyter notebook runing on a docker container.

I've launched the mongo server using:
`docker run --name some-mongo -p 27016:27017 -v /home/mongo/mongo_data:/data/db -d mongo`

mapping port `27016` to `27017`

When I run `docker ps` I get :

```
mongo@MongoServer:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
a2fd6b530ae4        mongo               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes       0.0.0.0:27016->27017/tcp   some-mongo
```

**EDIT :** `PORT 27016` was **not opened** on my EC2 instance

Here is the error message I get after trying to read the db using pymongo on jupyter :

```
from pymongo import MongoClient    
mongo_client = MongoClient('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 27016)
database_reference = mongo_client.new_york
collection_reference = database_reference.restaurants
collection_reference.count()
```

Error message :

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27016: timed out
```

Comment: Can you connect to port 27016 with the `mongo` command line tool on the server?

Comment: I can from the EC2 which runs the mongodb container :  
    `mongo@MongoServer:/usr/bin$ mongo 127.0.0.1:27016`
    `MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10`
    `connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27016/test`
    `Welcome to the MongoDB shell`
I can't from the other EC2 :
nicolasneiman@nicoUbuntu:~$ /usr/bin/mongo xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27016
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27016/test
2018-03-02T03:35:35.786+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27016 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed

Comment: I had not properly open the port on AWS :(
Thanks for the debugging advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open the `PORT 27016` on the EC2 instances